# Alternative for document.cookie in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, session-cookies

Any JavaScript code, other than "**document.cookie**" to view all the cookies in the browser?

Comment: Why do you need something other than `document.cookie`? That's what it's for.

Comment: You can perhaps issue an AJAX request and pick out the `Cookie` Header value from the xhr. But **why?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.cookie` is for getting/setting cookies - that's what you should use...

There is an alternative for local storage with javascript, which is conveniently called [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage) and [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage).

If you're looking for a library to make it easier to work with `document.cookie`, perhaps you'd be interested in this: [**jQuery Cookie (click).**](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/) Even better, MDN has a little library for working with cookies in **[these docs (click)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie)** (no need for jQuery).

Comment: by using document.cookie i can only get/set cookies on a particular tab.. but i need to access to all the cookies which are saved in the web browser.. thank you!

Comment: @JanithaMadushan are you trying to access cookies from other sites (not your own)? That's not possible for security purposes.

Comment: yes i know... but i am trying to develop a program. so i need to access all the cookies in the browser.. is that possible to do that??

Comment: @JanithaMadushan no, not all. You can access cookies from other domains if you can write code on each domain to allow it and make it work. It's not practical to do that, though.